# How to Get data in repeater from multiple table using like linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Code Behind:

```
Entities db = new Entities();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.BindRepeater();
        }
    }
    private void BindRepeater()
    {
        var q = from u in db.tbl_Question_Result
                join v in db.tbl_Question on
                u.Question_Id equals v.Question_Id 
                where u.Student_Id.Equals(1) && v.Paper_Id.Equals(5) select new {u,v};
        ResultRepeater.DataSource = q.ToList();
        ResultRepeater.DataBind();
    }
```

Front End:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ResultRepeater" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="row show-grid">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <span class="show-grid-block">
                                <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("u.Question_Obtained_Marks") %>"></asp:Label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                            <span class="show-grid-block">
                                <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel1" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("v.Question_Total_Marks") %>"></asp:Label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                            <span class="show-grid-block">
                                <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel2" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("v.Question_Question") %>"></asp:Label>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Error:
I got this error on line where i use Eval Fuction.

Parser Error
Description:An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are not properly formatted the quotes of your controllers.
Please try change

```
"<%# Eval("v.Question_Question") %>"
```

to following

```
'<%# Eval("v.Question_Question") %>'
```

and all other places as well.